# raid5 configuration on new dell server, sbs, win2008r2

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, raid, hardware-raid, windows-sbs-2011, gpt

Looking for a bit guidance configuring hardware raid on a new dell t610, I am basically trying to install Hyper-vR2 as the parent OS, then I will run SBS11 and WIin2008R2 virtually on top of that.

The raid card is a Perc H700 and it has 4 2TB sata disks.

WHen I set it up I create one virtual hard disk (from raid console) but when I try and load Hyper-V I get this weird partitioning error.

I have tried converting the disk to GPT as it is over 2TB, but then I cannot install Windows on a GPT partition. I think I need to create two virtual disks from the raid console but it will only allow me to make one.....

When it came out the box it had two virtual disks, but I wanted to change config as SBS11 was the host os.

Thanks for any guidance.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly don't do RAID 5 please, it's appalling and bad for your data's health, especially on large slow drives such as yours. If you look around on SF you'll find dozens of detailed reasons why but seriously don't use R5, use R10 instead.

Now onto your problem, I think you're booting your server using BIOS not EUFI firmware. It's a common problem, BIOS based systems struggle with >2TB boot disks, EUFI does not. Try that and let us know how you get on.